# Как убрать во фрейме скролл, но заставить контент прокручиваться

Tags: html

Вот такой код не прокручивает содержимое:

```html
<iframe width="240px" height="340px" scrolling="no" srcdoc="Левая колонка  orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Debitis exercitationem facere numquam dolor repellendus laudantium deserunt, corrupti nisi tempore, hic officiis enim iusto sapiente voluptas commodi. Officiis ea molestias, consequatur distinctio corporis iure amet. Reiciendis doloribus asperiores accusantium, aut quidem eligendi ipsum dolorum, expedita ab eum facer">
 </iframe>
```

Answer (score 4):

В вебките можете удалить его с помощью `css`:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:0;
}
```

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста, куда его вставить?

Comment: тот блок который вам нужно пишете стиль - #block ::-webkit-scrollbar {width:0}, но это будет работать только в webkit браузерах

Comment: понятно, а как быть с -moz и -ms

Comment: накрываем скроллящийся div еще одним div со свойством overflow: hidden, с размером поуже, чем скроллящийся на размер самого скрола, и этим закрываем скролы во всех браузерах